# Returning pointer from function

Tags: c++, pointers

Why this code doesn't work?
I have already found a workaround by passing a pointer to the function but I wonder if there is an easier solution?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* func() {
        int d[3];
        for (int f = 0; f < 3; f++)
                d[f] = 42;
        return d;
}


int main() {
        int* dptr;
        dptr = func();

        printf("Hi\n");

        for (int f = 0; f < 3; f++)
                 printf("%d\n",dptr[f]);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use English for your question text.

Comment: This is an English language site. Please post in that language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest workaround would be to use std::array (which is the prefered method)

```cpp
#include <array>

std::array<int, 3> do_something() {
   std::array<int, 3> arr = {1, 2, 3};
   return arr;
}

int main() {
    do_something()[0];
}
```

Best part about this is that the compiler will in-place construct this, meaning no performance was lost due to the copy.

Comment: 'return value optimization'

Comment: Oh i thought i mentioned the name, yeah it's called return value optimization, or RVO, in C++17 almost all cases will benefit from RVO, meaning that performance loss is minimal

Answer (score 3):

With `return d;`, you are returning a pointer to a local variable, i.e array `d`'s live time will end once function `func` has finished. Accessing this array afterwards (through the returned pointer) is undefined behaviour.

A simple solution would be to make `d` a `static` variable, such that its lifetime is will last until the program ends:

```
int* func() {
    static int d[3];
```

But note that this variable `d` will then exist only once in the program, such that the result of one call may be altered later. Consider to use `std::vector<int>` as return type or passing the array to be altered as function parameter `void func(int[] d) {`

Comment: Static variable can be problematic because callers usually don't expect that returned data may change after next function call. Also not thread safe. Better make iterator or range interface to pass array as modifiable arguments or return a container like `std::vector`.